# How to troubleshoot enq: TX - row lock contention?

Tags: oracle, locking, wait-types

I have the following situation.

I have RAC. On both nodes there are the locks.

## On the First Node

```
    SID EVENT                           USERNAME    BLOCKING_SESSION    ROW_WAIT_OBJ#   OBJECT_NAME LOCKWAIT            SQL_ID          STATUS
1   102 enq: TX - row lock contention   MYUSER      155                 136972          TABLE1V     0000000810EFA958    5f4bzdg49fdxq   ACTIVE
2   111 enq: TX - row lock contention   MYUSER      155                 136972          TABLE1V     0000000810EFAC98    5f4bzdg49fdxq   ACTIVE
```

## Blocking session info

```
    SID EVENT                       USERNAME    ROW_WAIT_OBJ#   OBJECT_NAME LOCKWAIT    SQL_ID          STATUS
1   155 SQL*Net message from client MYUSER      136971          MyTABLEIMAGES_IDPK      4hw85z8absbjc   INACTIVE
```

## On the Second Node

```
    SID EVENT                           USERNAME    BLOCKING_SESSION    ROW_WAIT_OBJ#   OBJECT_NAME   LOCKWAIT          SQL_ID          STATUS
1   65  enq: TX - row lock contention   MYUSER      155                 137033          FactTABLE1V   0000000810EF9B58  1mznc2z75ksdx   ACTIVE
2   111 enq: TX - row lock contention   MYUSER      155                 136972          TABLE1V       0000000810EF9818  5f4bzdg49fdxq   ACTIVE
```

## Blocking session info

```
    SID EVENT                       USERNAME    ROW_WAIT_OBJ#   OBJECT_NAME  SQL_ID  STATUS
1   155 SQL*Net message from client MYUSER      127176          MYTableLOG           INACTIVE
```

## Additional Info : Blocking session SQL_TEXT

```
create or replace procedure ACTIONProcedureDELETE
(
p_ID NUMBER
)
 is

 cursor oldval is select r.id,r.sessionstatus
  from MyTABLEIMAGES  r where r.idparent=p_ID;

begin
       update  actionmyTableblock r  set r.status='False' where  ID=p_ID;

   for oldvalItem in oldval loop

    if oldvalItem.Sessionstatus='True' then
      update MyTABLEIMAGES r set r.sessionstatus='False' where r.id=oldvalItem.Id;
    else
      update MyTABLEIMAGES r set r.sessionstatus='True' where r.id=oldvalItem.Id;
    end if;
  end loop;

end ACTIONProcedureDELETE;
```

## How do I troubleshoot this ?

As you can see blocking session is INACTIVE but still locking.

If I `select v$sql_bind_capture` there is no value for `VALUE_STRING` for blocking session `sql_id`.

## From where to start?

I can guess that there is missing commit/rollback but application developer says "I have everything ok, I have written commit where it is necessary"

Please help.

Answer (score 7):

Query `v$transaction` on each node to see uncommitted sessions:

```
SELECT t.start_time, s.sid, s.serial#, s.username, s.status,s.schemaname, s.osuser
   , s.process, s.machine, s.terminal, s.program, s.module
   , to_char(s.logon_time,'DD/MON/YY HH24:MI:SS') logon_time
FROM v$transaction t, v$session s
WHERE s.saddr = t.ses_addr
ORDER BY start_time;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can avoid row lock contention by making sure that the row is available for update beforehand with a `SELECT FOR UPDATE` and either `WAIT X` or `NOWAIT`, e.g:

```
create or replace procedure ACTIONProcedureDELETE (p_ID NUMBER)
 is

 cursor oldval is select r.id,r.sessionstatus
  from MyTABLEIMAGES  r where r.idparent=p_ID FOR UPDATE NOWAIT;

 l_id NUMBER;

begin
   select id into l_id from actionmyTableblock where ID=p_ID 
      FOR UPDATE of status NOWAIT;

   update  actionmyTableblock r  set r.status='False' where  ID=p_ID;

   for oldvalItem in oldval loop

    if oldvalItem.Sessionstatus='True' then
      update MyTABLEIMAGES r set r.sessionstatus='False' where r.id=oldvalItem.Id;
    else
      update MyTABLEIMAGES r set r.sessionstatus='True' where r.id=oldvalItem.Id;
    end if;
  end loop;

end ACTIONProcedureDELETE;
```

If the row is locked, you will receive an ORA-00054 which is in most cases preferable to indefinite waiting.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the select for update skip locked which is more elegant and safer

Comment: I don't know enough about the problem to be able to tell if your answer is correct or not. However, it's a bit short - take a look at the others. Answers here should be accompanied by an expanation of some sort and possibly links to documentation! I have one link to a how-to on answering questions by Jon Skeet (more than 1M points on StackExchange) - maybe you'd like to look at it and try to follow its hints? p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)